# Refresh Jtable

Tags: refresh, jtable

I have a JTable created from Vector.
How can the JTable be refreshed to display new data that is added to the Vector?

Answer (score 17):

Your JTable should update automatically when a change to the TableModel happens.  I'm taking a leap here but I'm guessing that you're not using your own TableModel and just called the JTable constructor with your Vector.  In this case you can get a hook on the TableModel and cast it to a DefaultTableModel and then call one its notification methods to let the JTable know of a change, something like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(........));
```

What I would **really** recommend is using your own TableModel unless this is something very trivial, but the fact you're updating the data indicates it's not.

Check out the sun tutorial on [working with tables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), inparticular the section on [listening for data changes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange).

It might seem like more work up front, but it will save you alot of headaches in the long run and is *The Right Way* to do it

Comment: Well, In my table, first i transfer data from database into vectors, then put in `DefaultTableModel` object for showing into jtable. Now, when i update a row in my database by secting a row and clicking on created `editButton` and done update, I need to know how re-transfer data to vectors and then call `fireTableDataChanged()` to change. my code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282753/firetablerowsupdated-not-work-after-update-done-in-jtable

Answer (score 1):

I call the initTable method followed by loadTable(). I'm sure there's plenty of other ways but this works like acharm.

```
private void initBerkheimerTable() {
        tblBerkheimer = new JTable();
        tblBerkheimer.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new SelectionListener());
        tblBerkheimer.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        tblBerkheimer.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
            },
            new String[] {
                "Id", "Name", "Berkheimer PSD", "Rate", "Current PSD", "Current Rate"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
                String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class
            };
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
            }
            boolean[] columnEditables=new boolean[]{false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false};
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return columnEditables[column];
            }
        });
        scrollPane.setViewportView(tblBerkheimer);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

private void loadTable(){
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        try {
            PayrollPsdAuditing.payroll=Database.connectToSQLServerDataBase(PayrollPsdAuditing.payrollIni);
            ps=PayrollPsdAuditing.payroll.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT a.EMPLOYID, " +
                "   a.NAME, " +
                "   a.PSD_CODE, " +
                "   a.RATE, " +
                "   b.STRINGS_I_2 as CURRENT_PSD, " +
                "   c.lcltaxrt as CURRENT_RATE " +
                "FROM PYRL_PSD_VALIDATION a, " +
                "   EX010130 b, " +
                "   UPR41400 c " +
                "WHERE a.employid=b.empid_i " +
                "   AND c.localtax=b.strings_i_2");
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                Swing.fillJTable(tblBerkheimer,
                        new String[]{rs.getString("EMPLOYID").trim()
                            ,rs.getString("NAME").trim()
                            ,rs.getString("PSD_CODE").trim()
                            ,String.valueOf(rs.getDouble("RATE"))
                            ,rs.getString("CURRENT_PSD").trim()
                            ,String.valueOf(rs.getDouble("CURRENT_RATE")/100000)});
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Database.close(PayrollPsdAuditing.payroll);
        }
    }
```